# is there a way to "uninclude" a file with PHP?

Tags: php, include

I'm working on a PHP IRC Bot, and I'm currently working on the commands.

At the beginning of `main.php`, the script that starts the bot, it includes the `class_lib.php` file and instantiates the object of that class. I want to work on a `!reload` command, where it would "uninclude" the file and then reinclude it. Would that be possible, or would it be fine if I just `include`d it again when that command was sent?

**EDIT:** Basically, I want to be able to modify and reload the class without having to restart the bot.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to accomplish, or more specifically why. You can just reinstantiate the object with unloading and reloading the class definition.

Comment: Why a "new MyClass()" instance won't work?

Comment: never thought of that. I'll give it a try, lepe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just allow the object to reload the default settings, or restart, instead of what you describe? I'm pretty sure you can't do that anyways.

Also, don't try to load the object with the class_lib.php. Include the class file with the object, then where and when you need it, create your object. That way you can stop it, destroy the object, and then re-instantiate another object, which should accomplish what you want.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how to destroy the object

Comment: If you're destroying an object that has created database connections or other kinds of activities in which there are open resources, you should also create an $objectvar->destroy() function within the object class to shutdown all of the resources, save anything that needs to be saved, and THEN unset($objectvar).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Your last comment touches base with the problem that unsetting it caused.

Comment: Usually, when you have an object, you have two standard methods: __construct(), __destruct(). Read about them here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php Primarily, what you want to do in the constructor is start your connections, load in settings (internally/externally), create any dependent objects used by the class. Then, when the object is destroyed, the destructor is called, and makes sure to cleanup things like writing changes to files/databases, closing database connections, clearing sessions, etc... Read about OOP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Here's an example of when an "un-include" would be useful: Say you have a Class file and the file name needs to be changed [say, to comply with a new coding standard], but there's legacy code that the rename will break, so the file with the old name is not deleted, but instead, the class definition is moved to the new file.  And, in the old file, along with "require_once 'new_class_file_name.php';", an error logging class is included to log a warning whenever the old file is used.  It would be cleaner if this Error Logging class file could be un-included.

Comment: @ReverseEMF - The appropriate way is to refactor and modify the references to the old include (unless I'm somehow misunderstanding what you're suggesting, pointing to the *actual* file directly is preferred). PhpStorm and other code editors provide simple ways to do this. I also don't see why "scriptomagically unincluding" would be useful at all. Manually uninclude, move on.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. Revisit your design. Don't couple the definition of the class with the instantiation of the object.

Comment: the instantiation is done in main.php, whereas the definition is in class_lib.php.

Answer (score 1):

Am afraid there is no way to uninclude a file. If it is a function, you could generate a new function dynamically each time.

Check:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

You can assign a function to a variable and then clear that variable and assign it again.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I have to mention the following PHP-extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php

> The runkit extension provides means to modify constants, user-defined functions, and user-defined classes. It also provides for custom superglobal variables and embeddable sub-interpreters via sandboxing.

This would allow you to re-define classes, which happens upon parsing included files.

NOTE: I have not used this, I came upon it after researching if it was possible to somehow hotswap certain classes. I cannot vouch for the safety and can not supply hands-on info. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer..

You could create an array containing the files and then eval(file_get_contents($filename))

I've been working on my own IRC Client named PITC and that may be the method I might use, It's how i've done stuff before

Comment: include $filename does exactly the same thing.